# how to build stable NTP server

Tags: linux, rhel, time, ntp, chrony

we have in some room ( with no connection to internet network ) ,  linux redhat servers

we installed the NTP clients based on crhony service on all machines to sync to NTP server

now we want to build NTP server also based on chrony service

one issue that could on the NTP server is not correct time and date because unexpected issue , *so this also will be negative situation on the ntp clients*

**so what are the options to build stable NTP server**

Comment: Please define "_stable_"

Comment: Please explain how you propose to avoid the stated issue where the NTP server does not have the "_correct time and date_" if it's not connected to an upstream network time source. (GPS? MSF?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NTP servers are divided in stratums, being a first stratum those servers directly connected to GPS antennas, quantum clocks and stuff like that.

Since you don't have access to the internet thus not having access to external NTP servers, you must act as a stratum 0 server, and to do that you will need some mechanism to assure the time you are providing is to be trusted.

If you only relay in your BIOS clock you won't be able to provide that so you seem to be in trouble unless you are able to connect a GPS clock (or another trustable mechanism) to your servers.

Answer (score 1):

If your computers form a completely detached network, and all you want to ensure is that they are synchronized among each other, you don't need a dedicated NTP server but can instead define all participating computers as `peer`.

In order to achieve that, remove the `server` statement on all machines configured as clients before, and instead add `peer` directives for all machines on your detached network (you will also have to add an `allow` statement so that the machines can access each other). You then add `peer` statements on the machine previously configured as server.

Answer (score 0):

Far as I recall, you can buy a stand-alone box that uses a radio signal. You can buy a watch on that system for 30 bucks, but scientific research sites, astronomers and the like use time servers based on that. Try Amazon (meant as a joke, but you never know).

You could set up a system: 30-dollar watch, webcab, and some AI to see the watch going around. Great intern project.

Comment: Not a joke. Look up the USB GPS Dongle Module Vk-172 on amazon and on the various sites that tell you how to set up your own ntp server using the dongle. Time is accurate only to a few tenths of a second but this is likely good enough for an isolated network.